# Applet to JFrame Error

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, awt

I have looked at other questions like mine but they can't seen to help me with the current errors I am getting.

```
package ss;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import sun.audio.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Slimeshooter extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener {

    static AudioStream stream = null;
    static AudioStream stream2 = null;
    public static Graphics d;
    public static BufferedImage redS, blueS, orangeS, greenS, purpleS, yellowS;
    public static BufferedImage chosenSlime;
    public static BufferedImage goat;
    public static Image offscreen;
    public static boolean slimeSpawn;
    public static boolean changeSlime;
    public static int posX;
    public static int posY;
    public static int hits, misses;
    public static int secondsleft = 60;
    public static Thread th2;
    public static boolean finished = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void run() {
        String bgmusic = "bgmusic.wav";
        InputStream in2 = null;
        try {
            in2 = new FileInputStream(bgmusic);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            stream2 = new AudioStream(in2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        AudioPlayer.player.start(stream2);

        slimeSpawn = true;
        try {
            blueS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeBlue.png"));
            redS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeRed.png"));
            yellowS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeYellow.png"));
            orangeS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeOrange.png"));
            purpleS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimePurple.png"));
            greenS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeGreen.png"));
            goat = ImageIO.read(new File("goat.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            if (secondsleft > 0) {
                th2 = new Thread();
                try {
                    th2.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                secondsleft--;
            } else {
                finished = true;
                repaint();
            }

            if (slimeSpawn == true) {
                posX = (int) (Math.random() * 1860);
                posY = (int) (Math.random() * 958);
                int slimeColor = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
                if (slimeColor == 0) {
                    chosenSlime = blueS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;
                    repaint();
                }
                if (slimeColor == 1) {
                    chosenSlime = yellowS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;
                    repaint();
                }
                if (slimeColor == 2) {
                    chosenSlime = purpleS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;;
                    repaint();
                }
                if (slimeColor == 3) {
                    chosenSlime = greenS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;
                    repaint();
                }
                if (slimeColor == 4) {
                    chosenSlime = orangeS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;
                    repaint();
                }
                if (slimeColor == 5) {
                    chosenSlime = redS;
                    slimeSpawn = false;
                    repaint();
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public Slimeshooter() {
        init();
        run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Slimeshooter();
    }

    public void spawnSlime() {

        if (changeSlime == true) {
            repaint();
            posX = (int) (Math.random() * 1860);
            posY = (int) (Math.random() * 958);
            int slimeColor = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            if (slimeColor == 0) {
                chosenSlime = blueS;
                slimeSpawn = false;
                repaint();
            }
            if (slimeColor == 1) {
                chosenSlime = yellowS;
                slimeSpawn = false;
                repaint();
            }
            if (slimeColor == 2) {
                chosenSlime = purpleS;
                slimeSpawn = false;;
                repaint();
            }
            if (slimeColor == 3) {
                chosenSlime = greenS;
                slimeSpawn = false;
                repaint();
            }
            if (slimeColor == 4) {
                chosenSlime = orangeS;
                slimeSpawn = false;
                repaint();
            }
            if (slimeColor == 5) {
                chosenSlime = redS;
                slimeSpawn = false;
                repaint();

            }
        }
        changeSlime = false;
        repaint();
    }

    public void init() {
        setSize(2000, 2000);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        addMouseListener(this);
        offscreen = createImage(2000, 2000);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        spawnSlime();
        d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        d.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2500);
        d.drawImage(chosenSlime, posX, posY, this);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40));
        g.drawString("Hits: " + Integer.toString(hits), 10, 40);
        g.drawString("Misses: " + Integer.toString(misses), 10, 80);
        g.drawString("Time Left: " + Integer.toString(secondsleft), 10, 120);
        if (finished == true) {
            int divide = hits / misses;
            String divided = Integer.toString(divide);
            g.drawString("You finished with the hit miss ratio of ABOUT... " + divided, 10, 160);
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        String gunsound = "gun.wav";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(gunsound);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            stream = new AudioStream(in);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        AudioPlayer.player.start(stream);

        // Test if the player clicked the slime
        if ((e.getX() < posX + 50 && e.getY() < posY + 50) && (e.getX() > posX && e.getY() > posY)) {
            changeSlime = true;
            hits++;
        } else {
            misses++;
        }

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: bgmusic.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ss.Slimeshooter.run(Slimeshooter.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ss.Slimeshooter.init(Slimeshooter.java:178)
    at ss.Slimeshooter.<init>(Slimeshooter.java:123)
    at ss.Slimeshooter.main(Slimeshooter.java:127)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ss.Slimeshooter.run(Slimeshooter.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The file bgmusic.wav is in the correct folder, it was working before the conversion over to JFrame.

Oh and in case it helps, this is a game where slimes randomly appear on your screen and you have to click on them before the time runs out.

Comment: *"The file bgmusic.wav is in the correct folder"* - According to your error, it's not.  Where is the file stored relative to the rest of the project?

Comment: It's in the src folder, it worked while it was an applet, should it work now or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, misread that. If it's in the src directory, you can't use FileInputStream to read it, you'll need to use Class#getResourceAsStream instead

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.